# Get image of all associated product of a configurable product

Tags: php, magento

How can I show the image of all associated products of a configurable product?

Comment: i have a configurable product which has 3 associated product. now i want to show the images of all the associated product. Is that clear

Answer (score 5):

Did you try searching for any answer before asking it here? I just did and found the following on the first attempt:
[Magento configurable products : display images of sub product](http://www.webmasterbulletin.net/2010/08/magento-configurable-products-display-images-of-sub-product/1285)
[Image-Based Dynamic Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/5813/image-based_dynamic_configurable_products/)
[Magento: reload color images for configurable product](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-reload-color-images-for-configurable-product)